# How to get the common field from a list of object

Tags: java, arraylist, listobject

Say I have a class of Student contain in fields : firstName and surname

I then use this to create two lists

```
List<Student> classroomA = {["Ben","oreilly"], ["Jenna","Birch"]}
List<Student> classroomB = {["Alan","Messing"], ["Ben", "Mancini"], ["Helena","Wong"]}
```

How would I go about using these lists to get all Students with same name from the list :

```
List<Student> commonStudents = {["Ben","oreilly"],["Ben", "Mancini"]}
```

Would doing for loop on both list and doing a `classroomA.getfirstName().equals(classroomB.getfirstName())` 
the only way ?

Comment: What are those squre brackets mean here?

Comment: @Excelan it just means its an object Student[firstName, surname]. so classroomA has two students and classroomB has three students.

Answer (score 0):

[Use Java 8 Lambdas.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Below code gets all Bens from the list. If you want a particular field from the object (which is transformation), then use the map on filter stream.

```
  List<Student> AllBens = classA.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).
         filter(k -> StringUtils.isNotEmpty(k.getName()) && k.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Ben")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Ah interesting. Thank you for this @K139, i will look in to Lambdas